# Character and Numeric vectors, preserve decimal points in R

Tags: r, class, object, character, rounding

I am trying to convert a numeric vector into a character object but I want maintain my decimal points.  For example, observe the following code:

```
v <- c(2, 3.55)
```

When typing the vector into my console I will observe

> 2.00   3.55

However, if I use the `as.character(v)` function it returns

> "2" "3.55"

I would like to instead have it return

> "2.00" "3.55"

I have included a picture of the problem for completeness/clarity. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use `format(v)` to get the default formatting rather than `as.character()` Or if you want more control use a function like`sprintf`, for example `sprintf("%.02f", v)`